# C program without the C Standard Library. How to?

Tags: c

All C language software I have seen so far makes extensive used of the so-called "*C Standard Library*", a piece of software that is part of (or actually **is**) the C standard itself. So, whatever the moderators think, this is not a book nor a commercial software.
It's instead the basic software library containing the implementation for stuff like `malloc()`, `printf()` and `strcpy()` and is usually bundled with all systems.

Now, I need to write some software in C language **without** using that library as it's neither available nor viable in that environment.
But I still need to read and write files and sockets.

Any idea or pointer to similar problems or environments?

Comment: If you don't like `FILE*`, then use your kernel's I/O calls instead. The point of the C library is to introduce portability and a common API layer

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using an alternative library? The standard C library is the only library that's standard across all C implementations.

Comment: **Why do you ask** ?

Comment: While worded as it is now, question is clearly off-topic (and now closed as such), the idea itself should occur to every aspiring C programmer who has a brain. Therefore the amount of down votes and questions asking why do you ask are a bit... disappointing. But you got a good answer still :-)

Comment: A C library is a layer between the C program and the OS thus also pushing a certain paradigm at a definite cost. The Standard C library is one. I am not interested in portability but in other tings like efficiency and alternative paradigms.

Comment: +1 for the question not deserving such downvotes.  Though it reminds me of that [commercial for string cheese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG7273yDpdA): *"Give me a pizza, but hold the tomato sauce.  And hold the crust."*

Comment: @Moderators. The question "I need to write a program in C without using the C standard library. How to?" I would have achieved the same goal without "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". I would then ask you to reconsider the "off-topic" tag.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths, etc. Please reconsider your decision: read the question again and possible my comments.

Comment: I reworded it, added comments too. But the question has kept its status of closed! Ah!

Answer (score 2):

Stricto sensu, a portable (hosted) C99 program not using the standard library is even unable to make any input/output, or probably make any observable side effect. And you won't even be able to allocate any data in the heap (like `malloc` does). BTW a libc is sort-of required by any C99 hosted implementation; you want a freestanding library for C (and it would by definition be "implementation specific"; indeed it could use OS specific services in an implementation specific way. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2089619/841108)).

On old Linux (and IIRC, SVR4 e.g. SunOS 5), there used to be some `libsys` which only interfaced the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). AFAIK, it is deprecated, and I cannot find it.

Some libraries (like [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) from GTK, ....) are offering equivalent of most standard C library functions (but they are expecting some libc, i.e. a hosted POSIX system).

Notice that you might consider using [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) and perhaps remove the functions you don't want from it. You could also consider using some libc providing a *subset* of the standard, e.g. [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/). See also wikipage on [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library).

BTW, you might have issues in coding in C any user-land Linux application which does not use the libc (e.g. because of [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)).

The strange thing is that I cannot today even name a free software language which is not using somehow C. In principle that could be possible (e.g. on Linux compiled to only call the syscalls), but I don't know anything like that.

Notice however that (at least on Linux) if you code a statically linked binary which *does not* call any standard C function, that binary will embark only a small portion of the libc (the one reachable from crt0).

Some standard library facilities (like [setjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) or [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html)...) usually require -or at least profit from- some compiler magic (even `malloc`, `printf`, `free` do with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Some of the standard library functions are not implementable in portable C.

If using `gcc` don't forget the `-ffreestanding` option to `gcc` in that case. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524844/841108).

Refer to [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), a (draft) C11 standard almost similar to the ISO one, or to [n2573](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2573.pdf), close to the C20 standard. See also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and this [C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Examples of freestanding open source applications includes the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), but there are many others on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) and mentioned on [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/), but also for [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) or [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.org/). I recommend downloading their source code and studying it for inspiration.

<sup>NB: you could consider that there are two dialects of the C99 language: the hosted C which contains standard libc functions like `fprintf`, `malloc`, etc... and starts with `main` ... and the freestanding C which does not contain them (but do contain `setjmp` etc...) and has no starting conventions.</sup>

Comment: Since every hosted implementation is required to provide a standard C library, it should be OK for the replacement to depend on it.

Comment: You can use C as a mere "high level assembly". If you have an alternate way to interact with the OS you don't need the StdLibC.

Comment: @Enzo: you are right if you think of freestanding C. Hosted standard C99 *requires* functions like `malloc`, `setjmp`, `fprintf` ...

Comment: Basile, it looks like the answer to my question lies between "there is none" and "I don't know". For example, I doubt that the Linux kernel contains any malloc, fprintf or setjmp. Nonetheless it's C. Very likely something in between C99 and C11. What I am talking is something about the library used in that kernel. I don't mind (and didn't asked) about C99/C11 compliance. I just need a "library" capable more or less of the same features of the "C standard library". Will I have issues? Well, that will be my job!